# raspberry pi raspbian3.10.25+ linux headers

Tags: linux, module, kernel, raspbian

How can I get the linux headers for the raspbian?

There is no installation package for it. Also I tried to download the sources
but in didn't work.

hi the following tutorials
http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=71&t=17666

http://sandsoftwaresound.net/raspberry-pi/build-a-kernel-module/

But it  still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Linux kernel source installer

i have found a linux kernel source installer. it works !!!
the script can install and prepare the kernel source for the running kernel.

> This makes it easy to build kernel modules, both in-tree and external.
>   It works on a fresh Raspian image and on a rpi-update'd image.
>
> Wiki: https://github.com/notro/rpi-source/wiki
>
> Some examples: https://github.com/notro/rpi-source/wiki/Examples-on-how-to-build-various-modules

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=76261

Answer (score 0):

You can find many things concerning the Raspberry Pi and Linux on [Github](https://github.com/raspberrypi). You can for example find [there](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux) several Linux kernels version sources (in branches) that you can compile to get headers.

Answer (score 0):

to get Raspbian kernel headers you should install `rpi-source` and have the latest firmware

on Raspberry follow those steps :

1 Perform an `sudo rpi-update`  you have to be on the latest firmware to do next  steps. see [ https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update ] for details on rpi-update .

2 Install and run `rpi-source` to install the source code that built the latest kernel that you are running. Instructions to install rpi-source can be found at [ https://github.com/notro/rpi-source/wiki ] .
This will create the correct entry in `/lib/modules` for the kernel that you are running.

if you have space problem error : `Not enough diskspace (900MB) on /root` , see [ https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/16977/download-kernel-source-code-error-not-enough-diskspace-900mb-on-root ] to resize the partition to be able to use the remaining free space on the SD card.